# Query for joining and counting some data from multiple tables - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want for given date time range to get:

- Airport name,
- Number of flights of that airport (number of times where that airport is arrivalAirport in Flight, while departureDate of that same Flight is in the given datetime range),
- Number of sold tickets of that airport (dateOfSale has to be in the given datetime range) and
- Total price of those sold tickets of that airport.

I have 3 tables (Airport, Flight and Ticket):

```
Airport data:
    id | name
    1  , Madrid Airport
    2  , Amsterdam Airport
    3  , Belgrade Airport
----------------------------------------------
Flight data:
    id | number |   departureDate   |    arrivalDate    |  departureAirport  |  arrivalAirport  | price
    1  , 101    ,2019-01-29 19:21:44,2019-01-29 22:21:44,  Madrid Airport    , Amsterdam Airport, 600
    2  , 102    ,2019-01-29 22:21:44,2019-01-30 00:21:44,  Madrid Airport    , Belgrade Airport , 450
    3  , 103    ,2019-01-30 20:21:44,2019-01-30 22:21:44,  Belgrade Airport  , Amsterdam Airport, 555
    4  , 104    ,2019-02-10 20:21:44,2019-02-10 22:21:44,  Belgrade Airport  , Madrid Airport   , 555
----------------------------------------------
Ticket data:
    id | FlightId | dateOfSale
    1  , 3        , 2019-01-23 00:00:00
    2  , 3        , 2019-01-27 10:00:00
    3  , 1        , 2019-01-27 13:00:00
```

Example datetime range:

- Minimal: 2019-01-25 19:21:44
- Maximal: 2019-02-02 00:00:00

With the given datetime range, only fourth flight will not pass condition because its departureDate is not in the given range, other three flights will pass.

So now, we have Amsterdam Airport (x2) and Belgrade Airport (x1) as an arrivalAirports. 
So first two columns should be represented like this:

```
Name of Airport  | Number of Flights | 
Amsterdam Airport, 2
Belgrade Airport , 1
```

Third one represents number of sold tickets while dateOfSale is also in the given datetime range.

In the ticket's table 3 tickets are sold, first two are bought for flight with id=3 and third ticket is bought for flight with id=1. 
Since first ticket's dateOfSale is not in the given datetime range, **only 2nd and 3rd ticket will pass**, and they both represent arrivalAirport called Amsterdam Airport.

So end result should be:

```
Name of Airport  | Number of Flights | Number of sold tickets | Total price
Amsterdam Airport, 2                 , 2                      , 1155
Belgrade Airport , 1                 , 0                      , 0
```

I tried something like this:

```
select a.name, count(f.arrivalAirport) as 'number of flights', 
count(t.dateOfSale) as 'number of sold tickets', sum(f.price) from airport a, 
flight f, ticket t where a.name = f.arrivalAirport and f.departureDate > 
'2019-01-25 19:21:44' and f.departureDate < '2019-02-02 00:00:00' and 
t.flightId = f.id and t.dateOfSale > '2019-01-25 19:21:44' and t.dateOfSale 
< '2019-02-02 00:00:00' group by a.name;
```

Doing only this, it counts number of sold tickets exactly like it should but number of flights are wrong.

I am not sure how to proceed any further. What am I missing in this query and can it be done like this or it has to include join (with which I have problems also)?

Comment: Can we have a fiddle of same (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this? sry @Strawberry